# Why isn't my VSTS "Publish Artifact" task picking up my published folder?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a .NET Core 2 class library im trying to create an artifact for in VSTS (for NuGet publish, but that's next..)

My "Publish Build Artifacts" task can't find the folder i've published via `dotnet publish`.

`dotnet publish` output:

```
2018-03-21T06:11:41.2709655Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish D:\a\1\s\src\xxx\xxx.csproj --configuration release --output D:\a\1\a\publish
2018-03-21T06:11:41.5475294Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.82.30579 for .NET Core
2018-03-21T06:11:41.5476483Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2018-03-21T06:11:41.5477091Z 
2018-03-21T06:11:42.5040403Z   Restore completed in 83.05 ms for D:\a\1\s\src\xxx\xxx.csproj.
2018-03-21T06:11:43.3434895Z   xxx-> D:\a\1\s\src\xxx\bin\release\netstandard2.0\xxx.dll
2018-03-21T06:11:43.9833363Z   xxx-> D:\a\1\a\publish\
```

The "Publish Build Artifacts" task just errors and says:

```
2018-03-21T06:11:44.9159833Z ##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\a\publish
2018-03-21T06:11:44.9209300Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Artifact
```

Even though the last line in the `dotnet publish` output matches the line.

This is what i have in VSTS:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your publish build artifacts task looks perfect, I think the problem lies in your dotnet publish task, can you show the configuration there?

Comment: You need to use dotnet pack to package project instead of dotnet publish (check my answer), regarding empty output issue of dotnet publish, you can share the detail log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: thanks for your help guys. dotnet pack was the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to use artifact for NuGet publish, you should use `Dotnet pack` to package the project, then publish to artifact, after that you can push package to server.

1. Remove .NET Core Publish task
2. Add .NET Core task before Publish Build Artifacts task (Command: pack)

Answer (score 2):

If your project is not a asp.net application, after building and before the "publish artifacts" you have to add a copy task, like this ...

[image]

Comment: this sounds right and makes sense.. but since i need a NuGet package published, i'm going to go with the other answer, which worked. but if i could choose two answers, i would. :) +1